# How to exit gracefully from a Vibe.d program using also a Websocket after Ctrl+C?

Tags: websocket, d, vibed

Adding as usual where it applies:

```d
scope (exit)
{
    listener.stopListening();
}
```

is not sufficient to close a **vibe.d** program gracefully by means of Ctrl+C when it also make use of **Websocket** implemented like so:

```d
routes.get("/ws", handleWebSockets(&handleWebSocketConnection));
```

`routes` being an instance of `URLRouter` and the related handler looks like so

```d
void handleWebSocketConnection(scope WebSocket socket)
{
    ...

    while (true) {
        ...

        if (!socket.connected) break;

        ...

        socket.send("xxxx");
    }

    ...
}
```